# How to generate dynamic tables with jquery by receiving json response from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want my output in following format. My design should be follows.[image: Output]

I want help to design the above method. Please can anyone help me. I am storing `rollno` in `student` table and `marks` in `marks` table. Mark table contains a reference to `student rollno`.

How can I send the json value to jquery ajax using php and assign the response to the page?

Or if you have any other method to do this. Please suggest that also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like,

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:'getStudMarks.php',
       data:{rollNo:'19GH24'},// get marks of student 19GH24 
       type:'POST',
       success:function(data){
          $('table tbody').html(data);
       }
    });
});
```

And in `getStudMarks.php` page return your data like,

```
<tr><td>C</td><td>90</td><td>98</td></tr>;
```

For multiple tables you needt to give `table id` like

```
<table id="table-19GH24">
    <thead>
       ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>....</tbody>
</table>
```

And in `success callback` use the `rollno` like,

```
$('#table-19GH24 tbody').html(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If i want to assign to multiple table upto student strength what i have to do. It should be like above image

Comment: Then you need to return `multiple rows` like, `<tr><td>C</td><td>90</td><td>98</td></tr>;<tr><td>C++</td><td>95</td><td>78</td></tr>;`

Comment: okay. got it.thank you. if i wantto give rollno as dynamic one. what i have to do. so that one rollno contains multiple receords such as c, c++ etc.. Please help me.thanks

Comment: If then roll numbers are dynamic then you need to create a table dynamically using that roll number. And then append it in `body`